# Highcharts navigator mouse over not working

Tags: highcharts

When I resize the navigator on the bottom from left and right the mouse over tooltip stops working, but it works fine when zoom is set to YTD or ALL, how can I fix this please? Thank you!

https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/anp4L9do/1

```
    series: [{
    type: 'spline',
    name: 'Price',
    point: {
      events: {
        mouseOver: function(e) {
          var point = this,
            chart = point.series.chart;

          chart.series[1].points[point.index].setState('hover');
        },
        mouseOut: function(e) {
          var point = this,
            chart = point.series.chart;

          chart.series[1].points[point.index].setState('normal');
        },
      },
    },
    states: {
      inactive: {
        opacity: 1
      }
    },
    data: [
      [1541514600000, 20100.92],
      [1543847400000, 18428.466]
    ]
  }, {
    type: 'column',
    name: 'Volume',
    data: [
      [1541514600000, 31882900],
      [1543847400000, 40802500]
    ],
    states: {
      inactive: {
        opacity: 1
      }
    },
    enableMouseTracking: false,
    yAxis: 1
  }]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An array with points is reduced to only the visible ones, use `data` array instead:

```
point: {
  events: {
    mouseOver: function(e) {
      var point = this,
        chart = point.series.chart;

      chart.series[1].data[point.index].setState('hover');
    },
    mouseOut: function(e) {
      var point = this,
        chart = point.series.chart;

      chart.series[1].data[point.index].setState('normal');
    },
  },
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/gnkjf8q9/

Comment: If you drag the navigator from right to the left and then scroll/move navigator to the right, and then mouse over the last bars they are not showing the tooltip, thank you for your help! @ppotaczek

Comment: Works fine in my case. Could you create some gif or something similar with the problem?

Comment: Please see this https://imgur.com/gHBmWv6 thank you! @ppotaczek

Comment: Ok, please check this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/wqaeg36c/ I though that the problem is related only with `mouseOver` and `mouseOut` events.

Comment: It's working properly now, but it stops working after 100+ data points, can you please check, thank you! @ppotaczek

Comment: The problem is probably caused by data grouping, please try to disable it: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vfbc2gw7/

Comment: It works, thank you for all your help!! @ppotaczek